# Grabbing only selected objects from S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

```
s3=boto3.resource('s3')
bucket=s3.Bucket('***')
prefix_objs=bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='****')
body=[]
for obj in prefix_objs:
    print(obj.key())
```

This chunk of code isn't returning any output. Ideally I would want to read in the multiple files into different dataframes.

The `prefix_objs` variable is returning the following:
`s3.Bucket.objectsCollection(s3.Bucket(name='****'), s3.ObjectSummary)`

Comment: What do you want to do with each object? Where is your code related to dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want to print out objects that start with specific prefix (like: logbucket-asdf, logbucket-qwerty and etc.). For such a case you can use this code:

```
bucket_name = 'paste your bucket name'
prefix = 'paste your prefix'
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
     if my_bucket_object.key.startswithprefix):
         print(my_bucket_object.key)
```

Or if you want to print out objects that contain specific element(like: myapp-logbucket, ic-data-logbucket-asdf, logbucket-erere and etc.) you can use the following example:

```
bucket_name = 'paste your bucket name'
prefix = 'paste your prefix'
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name) 


for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    if str(my_bucket_object.key).find(prefix) > -1:
        print(my_bucket_object.key)
```